# cucumber javascript enabled features inside vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, webkit, cucumber, vagrant

i am a big fan of both cucumber and vagrant. i am using cucumber to drive development with a BDD style and have configured and setup my dev environment once in a vagrant vm so it can be easily distributed to other developers.

i've hit a snag when it comes to testing js on the vagrant vm. i'm using capybara alongside cucumber and have tried both selenium and capybara-webkit as js drivers.

selenium wanted me to install firefox. so i packaged up the vagrantbox fully expecting it not to work and installed firefox on the vm.. after that it complained about being unable to get a stable connection with firefox. exact error message: 'unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds'

webkit complained about 'webkit_server: cannot connect to X server'.. i installed xserver-org and still no dice.

would much prefer if i didn't have to install my whole environment on my host in order to do testing as that would kind of defeat the purpose of having a distributable vagrant vm that has everything a dev needs to work on the app.

any ideas? i've encountered a similar problem with the notifications from guard, but that seems like not nearly as big a deal as this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all drivers require X, to be installed.
So on linux server I do not have how do it.

Other way it using Firefox from host machine via selenium remote.
It mean javascript will be run on remote Firefox on any machine.

[Remote Selenium WebDriver not responding to Cucumber tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908652/remote-selenium-webdriver-not-responding-to-cucumber-tests)

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

It work.

Run selenium server on host

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Changes in spec_helper.rb

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["network.http.use-cache"] = false

Capybara.register_driver :firefox_host do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    :url => 'http://10.0.2.2:4444/wd/hub',
    :desired_capabilities =>   Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => profile)
)
end

Capybara.server_port = 9300
Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:9300'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox_host
```

Changes in Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.forward_port 9300, 9300
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try running firefox headless.

http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/

This way, you can run tests without seeing them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Try ssh'ing into your VM and executing `xhost +` from the command line. This disables access control and allows clients to connect from any host to access your display.

Also, you might need to `export DISPLAY=:0` as well, because the webdriver will default to using this display when it launches Firefox.